# -webkit-transform: translate3d and -webkit-filter: grayscale bug in safari

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, grayscale, translate3d

```
.img1{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
.img2{
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1, 1);
}
```

Usage of `transform: translate3d` causes grayscale bug in safari 6.0.4 http://jsfiddle.net/xcrUc/19/ . What is the other way to rendering image to grayscale in safari or how can i fix that bug without changing `transform` property? This happens when i'm trying to grayscale yandex maps in safari.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in Safari (6.0.5). CSS transitions on other elements on the page cause elements with grayscale filters to flicker for the duration of the transition. No idea how to get around it :-(